# Reseting Computer from Bitlocker encryption key page

Tags: windows-10

I don't have a bitlocker key. And each time I select the option to reset the computer it keeps circling back to the bitlocker key page? Why want it reset. I don't even remember setting this up.

Answer (score 0):

First back any import documents up to a USB stick that isn't encrypted.

Download the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft and create a bootable USB, NOT the same stick as step 1 as this one will be reformatted.  Losing its previous contents.

Ensure you have a valid product key and/or get a utility to read it from registry.

Boot of the USB stick from step 2, and attempt to format the drive, and install windows.

There is a slight chance windows may not allow this.

In this case with the installation screen up press F8 or is it F10.  If that fails hold down the SHIFT key and press those buttons.  You will get a command prompt.

```
diskpart
list disk
--a list of disks appear---
select disk #
```

Make sure you don't accidently select your USB stick or another drive.

```
clean
exit
```

You may or may not have to restart, but the drive **should** be free of encryption.

Alternatively:

Boot from any live linux DVD or USB  (gparted?)
get to an admin terminal window
You can run gparted (some include this) to verify which drive you want to clear.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=65536 count=10000
```

This wipes out **ALL DATA** including traces of encryption, and make the disk appear blank.  You could omit the **count=10000** and do the whole drive, but that takes hours and is unnecessary for the task at hand.

Comment: "Ensure you have a valid product key and/or get a utility to read it from registry." - User is using Windows 10, this step, isn't required and is a complete waste of time.

Comment: Actual the OP won't have a valid windows 7 license unless they purchased one elsewhere.

Comment: @Ramhound only if they have an OEM key, which was sold with the PC, only if the PC was made industrially (i.e. not built in a shop or by themselves) and the mobo is compatible with the feature

Comment: @cybernard - The author is specifically using Windows 10.  What does Windows 7 have to do with the author's question?

Comment: @alex2003super - Even if they don't have an OEM key, a machine that has already had Windows 10 installed on it, will automatically be installed.  If we are talking about VLK licenses, then they key wouldn't have to be retrieved either, I have researched Windows 10 activation, I know what I am talking about, retrieving the Windows 10 license, is a waste of time